# Finding the longest common sequence

Tags: algorithm

I having reading the article  finding the longest common between two giving string.

I came to know about an algorithm which code as follow:

```
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<=m;j++){

        if(i==0 || j==0) dd[i][j]=0;
        else if(a[i-1]==b[j-1])
            dd[i][j] = 1 + dd[i-1][j-1];
        else{
            dd[i][j] = Math.max(dd[i-1][j], dd[i][j-1]);
        }
    }
```

I quit understand this but i could not understand how it work , i.e. what is the proof of working it correctly. Why this thing work please help me to understand the algorithm

Comment: Have you tried reading the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Code_for_the_dynamic_programming_solution)?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of resources you can find, if you google..

- [Word Aligned](http://wordaligned.org/articles/longest-common-subsequence)
- [GeeksforGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-4-longest-common-subsequence/)
- [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJ-rP9hJXO0)
- [PDF](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~meesh/351/mount/lectures/lect25-longest-common-subseq.pdf)

This is from the 1st link [Word Aligned]. There is good explanation with animation

[image]

Answer (score 0):

let,

```
str1 = "bcd"
str2 = "dabc"
```

here `n=3` and `m=4`

```
The outer loop is for str1 and inner loop is for str2
```

- 1st iteration is used to initialize the array.

Here is the first look of `dd` array :

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

- In 2nd iteration of the outer loop, it compares whole str2 with 1st character of str1, that is `"dabc" with 'b'`

now when `'b'` compares to `"dabc"`,we see that at 4th iteration there will be a match, so array value will be changed with respect to the corner value of current position. Current position is `[1][3]`. As corner `([0][2])` value is `0`, current value will be `1` :

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 1, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

At the end of the iteration the array will be like this :

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 1, 1
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

value of position `[1][4]` changed, because if a character of `str2` doesn't match with the current character of `str1`, then the value of the current position will be the max between the upper and left position of current position. Here max is `1`.

**Now check yourself, if `str1="b"` maximum match will be 1. That is we calculating the maximum match for each entry of `str1` in each iteration.**

- In 3rd iteration of the outer loop, it compares whole str2 again with 2nd character of str1, that is `"dabc" with 'c'`

now at 5th iteration there will be a match, so array value will be changed with respect to the corner value of current position. Current position is `[2][4]`. As corner `([1][3])` value is `1`, current value will be `2` :

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 1, 1
0, 0, 0, 1, 2
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

**Now check yourself, if `str1="bc"` maximum match will be 2. That is we calculating the maximum match for each entry of `str1` in each iteration.**

At the end of the iteration the array will be like this :

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 1, 1
0, 0, 0, 1, 2
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

- In 4th iteration of the outer loop, it compares whole str2 again with 3rd character of str1, that is `"dabc" with 'd'`

now at 2nd iteration there will be a match, so array value will be changed with respect to the corner value of current position. Current position is `[3][1]`. As corner `([2][0])` value is `0`, current value will be `1` :

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 1, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 2
0, 1, 0, 0, 0
```

no further matching will occur.

At the end of the iteration the array will be like this :

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 1, 1
0, 0, 0, 1, 2
0, 1, 1, 1, 2
```

So the LCS of these two string is `dd[3][4] = 2`.

Hope you understand this. You can also get help from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Code_for_the_dynamic_programming_solution)

**Note : Here i described only about matching situation. If one character of `str2` doesn't match with the current character of `str1`, then the value of the current position will be the max between the upper and left position of current position. Try it yourself, you will understand why we do this :)**